# Azure App Service Domain Verification - No App service app configured with the custom domain

Tags: ssl, azure, subdomain, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services

I have an existing custom sub-domain which I have mapped to my existing Azure App Service web app via CNAME. I have also assigned this custom sub-domain to my app service app via Azure portal successfully. I can see "HOSTNAMES ASSIGNED TO SITE" section as expected and also access my custom sub-domain to see default azure app service content page.

To buy SSL certificate I'm following steps on MS docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site).

I can't complete Step# 4 [Verify Domain Ownership](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#step-4---verify-the-domain-ownership). I selected App Service Verification method to verify ownership. However, I continue to see following message -

> No App service app configured with the custom domain : my-sub-domain

Comment: We had the same problem, which is not true that there's no App service with that custom domain. We ended up using manual verification method.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the Azure Portal and then re-check.

You can verify the DNS propagation by going to this URL http://digwebinterface.com/

Specify the hostnames in the textbox and click on Dig. Verify the results to confirm if the recent changes have taken effect